# How to get steps and current value, after clicking on up/down control of QDoubleSpinBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

My question is, **how can I get the control of stepSize and "currentvalue" before "value" in the spinbox(`I required double spinbox (QDoubleSpinBox`)) gets incremented/decremented ?**

**Note:**
*I know, "valueChanged" signal is there but, slot gets called only after currentvalue incremented/decremented*

Comment: IMO you messing up the logic! Why you need change `stepSize` just before `valueChanged`? What do you gain? I'm pretty sure you know new step immediately after change of value, so long before a new change. Maybe you have some other data which will have impact on `stepSize`. In such case it is possible to do it in different way, give some more details on the problem.

Comment: BTW `stepBy` doesn't define step size, but performs change by given number of *steps*, so it doesn't meter what typo of step is it.

Comment: I need change stepSize just before valueChanged, Because I need to use logarithmic value increment, so I need to change stepSize, before increment/decrement.

Comment: So my answer is Ok, I will improve it to take into account new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second comment I'm pointing out that you misunderstand functionality of `QAbstractSpinBox::stepBy`.

So when you subclass `QDoubleSpinBox` you can do it like that:

```
void SubclassOfDoubleSpinBox::stepBy(int steps) {
    if (steps>0) {
       if (steps>=10) { // note some events call stepBy with step value 10 or -10
           setSingleStep(incrementStep10());
       } else {
           setSingleStep(incrementStep1());
       }
    } else {
       if (steps<=-10) {
           setSingleStep(decrementStep10());
       } else {
           setSingleStep(decrementStep1());
       }
    }

    QDoubleSpinBox::stepBy(steps);
}
```

this will do the job with logarithmic increment decrement logic.